# HP F2180 driver installation fails on 64-bit Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I am trying to install the HP Deskjet AIO (non-network) driver on my machine, which is running the 64-bit version of Windows 7.

Before installing it, Windows detected my printer just fine... But I wanted to use the HP scanning application, because tt allows me to scan several photos at once.

I ran the `DJ_AIO_NonNetwork_ENU_NB` file I got from their site, and the installation went *almost* without a problem... However, at the part where it should have detected the printer, it didn't, so I skipped it - telling the installer I'll connect the printer later. After it was finished I was able to use it regularly, and also scan using the wanted HP application.

However, the installer kept popping at random intervals, and giving me an error message.
Yesterday I tried removing all the installed HP Applications, and installing from scratch.  Running the same installer setup, it now insists that it does not support my operating system, and that 64-bit Vista is the highest it can go... I just don't understand *why* this is occuring all of the sudden.

Has anybody here successfully installed the AIO driver on the 64-bit version of Windows 7?

### UPDATE:

Been chatting with HP chat support over the weekend. Managed to really mess up my windows. At first, they told me to uninstall using an "unintall_l3" batch file inside their installer package, and then reinstall. Didn't work. Also the "l4" batch didn't make any difference. Afterwards I was told to install "Windows install clean up" and remove many hp entries (most of which were not listed on my computer), and I also removed many other hp entries I bumped upon. Then my office 2k7 started failing. I searched around the web, and ran [Security Restore](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/restore-default-security-settings-fix-win7-errors/), so now my office works, but my windows  explorer is all buggy - can't seem to open windows explorer - it hangs while trying to load my hard drives, or completely ignores them and just shows my libraries.

Anyone here has any idea how I can restore my win7 to normal, with or without the annoying scanner?

### UPDATE 2:

Ok - explorer back to normal. I guess I just had to wait until it finishes searching while opening the windows explorer for the first time after the Security Restore. Scanner still not working though.

Comment: Just adding - I have found 'DJ_AIO_NonNet_Full_Win_WW_130_140' file, and 
 successfully installed it on a laptop with win7 x64, connected to the exact same printer at my house. Everything worked just fine.
I uninstalled the driver on my desktop, reinstalled the new file, and the problem remains. Can't scan using the HP application.
What a pain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no good news - but I have recently purchased a new HD, and installed a brand new win7 x64 on it, instead of my old system. ran the same `DJ_AIO_NonNet_Full_Win_WW_130_140` setup on it, and scan just works now (needless to say, I still have the same old crappy f2180 printer).

So I don't know what caused the original problem, or how to fix it, but formatting the system disk did solve it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the installer in [Compatibility Mode](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html)?

Failing that, you can try to manually extract the installation executable with a third-party program (e.g. [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) or [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)), and see if there is any nested installers... You should be able to at least extract the drivers without a hitch.